# Multi-Level Inheritance in Joined Inheritance strategy using discriminator for each parent in hierarchy

Tags: hibernate, jpa, inheritance, discriminator, joined-subclass

Consider my classes below

**Product** (Abstract Root class)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCT")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="PRODUCT_TYPE")
public abstract class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "product_ent_id", insertable = false)
    private int productEntId;
}
```

**Car** (Another parent class that extends Product)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CAR")
@DiscriminatorValue(value="Car") 
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="car_ent_id") 
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="CAR_TYPE") 
public abstract class Car extends Product {

    @Column(name = "car_ent_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int carEntId;
}
```

**Speeder** (last child of the hierarcy that extends Car)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SPEEDER")
@DiscriminatorValue(value="Speeder") 
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="speeder_ent_id")
public class Speeder extends Car {

    @Column(name = "speeder_ent_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int speederEntId;
}
```

Using discriminator in a single parent-to-child hierarchy was doing fine to me when JPA maps my       object model into my data model using discriminators, the discriminator values are properly set, but as I added another level of hierarchy which is **Speeder-extends-Car-extends-Product**, the discriminator values or not working properly,

[image: PRODUCT table]
[image: CAR table]
[image: SPEEDER table]

If I'm only using joined inheritance using discriminator in a single inheritance(e.g. child-to-parent), the discriminator value is being mapped properly in their respected columns, but now I **added another hierarchy, the Speeder's discriminator value** is the one being placed in the **Product table's discriminator column**, and the **discriminator column** of the **Car table** is left as null value, I hope you can understand what I'm trying to achieve here, is this possible? any work arounds? there are so many examples around, but I cant find exactly one that illustrates a deeper hierarchy, an example like this [joined inheritance tables](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#Example_joined_inheritance_tables_in_database) but with a deeper hierarchy, the examples around has only simple hierarchy and almost the same with the others using this kind of strategy. Any help or enlightenment would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: thanks, any suggestion for making this kind of design possible?

Comment: if it is not possible any suggestion please? thanks